# li:hover>a affecting other list items

Tags: css, hover

What I am trying to do is to get the hover effect that puts the anchor link a bit down, but somehow it affects all the links. Can somebody point out what I did wrong here?

```css
nav {
      width: 100%;
      height: 5rem;
      background: red;
    }
    
    ul {
      margin: 0 auto;
      font-size: 0;
    }
    ul li {
      display: inline-block;
      line-height: 4.8rem;
      position: relative;
    }
    ul li > a {
      text-decoration: none;
      color: #FFF;
      font-family: "Verdana";
      padding: .1rem 1.5rem;
      font-size: 1.3rem;
      display: block;
      overflow: hidden;
      position: relative;
      transition: 300ms all;
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0;
    }
    ul li > a::before, ul li > a::after {
      content: '';
      width: 100%;
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      transition: 200ms all;
    }
    ul li > a::before {
      background: #FFF;
      height: .5rem;
      top: 0;
      transform: translateY(-100%);
    }
    ul li > a::after {
      background: #000;
      height: .4rem;
      bottom: 0;
      transform: translateY(100%);
    }
    ul li::before {
      content: '';
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      background: #CCC;
      position: absolute;
      opacity: 0;
    }
    ul li:hover > a {
      padding-top: 0.6rem;
      padding-bottom: 0.1rem;
    }
    ul li:hover > a::before, ul li:hover > a::after {
      transform: translateY(0);
    }
    ul li:hover::before {
      opacity: 0.3;
    }
```

```html
 <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="">Link1</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Link2</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Link3</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Link4</a></li>
        <li><a href="test.html">Link5</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
```

Why `li:hover > a` is affecting all list items?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not your `:hover` selector, it's the `display-block` on the `li`s. `inline-block`elements align on the baseline, this means that when you add a `padding-top`to one of them, all the others move down as well. To fix it float the elements to the left to keep them on one line and aligned to the top:

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/403zexop/

```
nav {
    width:100%;
    height:5rem;
    background:red;
}

ul {
    margin:0 auto;
    font-size:0;
    overflow: hidden;
    li {
        display:block;
        line-height:4.8rem;
        position:relative;
        float: left;

        >a{
            text-decoration:none;
            color:#FFF;
            font-family:"Verdana";
            padding:.1rem 1.5rem;
            font-size:1.3rem;
            display:block;
            overflow:hidden;
            position:relative;
            transition:300ms all;
            height:100%;
            margin:0;

            &::before,&::after{
                content:'';
                width:100%;
                position:absolute;
                left:0;
                transition:200ms all;
            }

            &::before{
                background:#FFF;
                height:.5rem;
                top:0;
                transform:translateY(-100%);
            }
            &::after{
                background:#000;
                height:.4rem;
                bottom:0;
                transform:translateY(100%);
            }
        }

        &::before{
            content:'';
            width:100%;
            height:100%;
            top:0;
            left:0;
            background:#CCC;
            position:absolute;
            opacity:0;
        }

        &:hover{
            >a{
                padding-top:0.6rem;
                padding-bottom:0.1rem;

                &::before,&::after{
                transform:translateY(0);
            }
        }

        &::before{
            opacity:0.3;
        }
    }
}

}
```

Note: I cleared the floats by adding `overflow: hidden;` to the  `ul`

Comment: Thank you for the help and i wasn't aware of baseline problem of inline-block elements .I chose inline-block instead of float for the benefits of vertical-align , text-align and the use of line-height . But after this i feel using it a bit awkward along with the 4px margin problem . What is your best option for such menus float, inline-block or flex ?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean with "the 4px margin problem", could you rephrase that, please? I personally would float those elements and then use the line-height or padding to center the text vertically.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078239/how-to-remove-the-space-between-inline-block-elements

Comment: Oh I see. I usually go for the floats, I only use inline-blocks when I want that white space between elements (icons before the text, etc). Floats are a little bit annoying because you have to clear them but inline-blocks have even more downsides. I don't use flex yet because of the browser support

Answer (score 0):

"li:hover > a" is correct!

The problem is, that with changing the padding you alter the height of the element, and the parent container has to adapt and as well all other childs.

You can see it when you do not change the padding, but just the background-color of the hovered a. You will see, it is just altering the current element.

Comment: Please see my answer. The problem is not even the padding itself, it's that the elements are aligned on the baseline due to the inline-block.